# How to verify the formula $\sum_{i=2}^n \binom{i}{2} = \binom{n+1}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics

How to verify the formula $\sum_{i=2}^n \binom{i}{2} = \binom{n+1}{3}$?

I tried to apply induction. We can quickly check that the formula holds for $n=2$, now by inductive hypothesis $\sum_{i=2}^k \binom{i}{2} = \binom{k+1}{2}$. The inductive step would be to show that $\sum_{i=2}^{k+1} \binom{i}{2} = \binom{k+1+1}{2}$.

So we re-write left hand side of inductive step to be $\sum_{i=2}^{k} \binom{i}{2} + \binom{k+1}{2} = \binom{k+1}{2} + \binom{k+1}{2}$? My problem is I don't see how this last step can equate to $\binom{k+2}{2}$.

Edit: This is not an identity that holds. Thank you for the suggestions that it this $\sum_{i=2}^n \binom{i}{2} = \binom{n+1}{3}$ instead is true

Comment: How did you prove the basis?  This is clearly false when $n=2$

Comment: The result does not hold when $n=3$ for example. The LHS is ${2\choose 2}+{3\choose 2}=4$ but the RHS is ${4\choose 2}=6$.

Comment: I think you have a typo.  In the RHS, the 2 should be a 3.

Comment: Indeed[$\sum_{k=2}^n \binom n 2 = \binom{n+1}{3}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5B+binom%5Bk%2C+2%5D%2C%7Bk%2C2%2Cn%7D%5D+%3D+binom%5Bn%2B1%2C3%5D)

Comment: I think Pascal’s Identity might help , if R.H.S. is $3$.

Comment: To whoever downvoted: I was surprised by this and upvoted to reverse the downvote.  The OP clearly made a significant effort and (furthermore) showed it in his query.  His only problem was an honest mistake, which I don't think deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to prove a wrong thing (as in, it is not in fact true).

You should be proving: $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=2}^n\dbinom k2=\dbinom{n+1}3$, which is actually true for any integer $n$ that is at least $2$.

First: It does indeed hold for $n=2$, as $\dbinom 22=\dbinom 33$.

Next: When assuming that the premise holds for an arbitrary integer, $n$, in $\{2...\infty\}$, we can derive that it holds for the subsequent, $n+1$, too:$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\binom {k}2 &= \binom{n+1}3+\binom{n+1}2&&\text{under the assumption}\\&=\dfrac{(n+1)\,n\,(n-1)}{3!}+\dfrac{(n+1)\,n}{2!}\\&~~\vdots\\&=\dbinom{n+2}{3}\end{align}$$